# context free grammar and removing left recursion

Tags: context-free-grammar, left-recursion

The following grammar has left recursion

```
  E -> E + T|T
  T -> T * F|F
  F -> F*|a | b
```

How to remove it? Is there any general procedure for it?

Comment: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node8.html

Comment: thanks but the idea of removing left recursion i understand it. the problem is with this particular questions especially the last line "F->F*|a|b" . i want help on that

Comment: If you understand the idea of removing left recursion, then what is your question?  I mean, if you understand, you would know the general procedure.  youtube has plenty of examples.

Comment: i faced challenges on this expression  F ->  F* |a |b. thats where i need help removing the left recursion. @Jerry

Comment: @Sunil B N I Kindly ask you to remove the left recursion on the above problem showing the steps involved.